# Why do I get a 550 FTP error with Filezilla, but IE6 is fine?

Tags: windows, filezilla, internet-explorer-6

When transferring some files today from our hosted FTP site, which a client had uploaded, for files in certain directories I kept getting (using Filezilla):

```
Command:    RETR /dir/file.jpg
Response:   550 /dir/file.jpg: No such file or directory
Error:  Critical error
```

However, when I tried transferring the same files using IE6 (against my better judgement) they went fine. Why is this?

Comment: Hmmm, today the Community user's random poking around made this question appear on the home page of Super User again. Too bad you abandoned it, Skilldrick!

Comment: Hola, Community poked this onto the front page once more. I guess it's time for a downvote to keep that from happening... ;-)

Comment: Mean! Unfortunately I never got a satisfactory answer. Guess it's just one of those mysteries.

Comment: It's not like you responded to my answer either..

Comment: Hmmm, my answer got accepted for being the best out of one :-) But was it *solved* then...?

Comment: No, but I'll never be able to reproduce the problem so it doesn't matter for me. It's probably a useful answer for someone else's similar problem, so it might as well be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you were transferring the files in IE6 using HTTP? An image with a URL like www.example.com/dir/file.jpg is not likely to be stored in the /dir folder in the root of the file system.

If the home folder of the FTP account is the directory that holds the web site document, then you could try without the leading slash.

If you were using IE6 as an FTP client, then the only thing I can think of: spaces in the file name? Or maybe a different setting in [Active/Passive FTP](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html), though then the error message is quite stupid, and it should then happen for all files.

(Any success in IE6 is no excuse not to [uninstall it](http://www.stopie6.com/).)